# Can a RS-232 COM port damage the motherboard's SATA controller?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, sata, rs232, com

We have a chromatograph connected to a computer through one of those old COM ports (RS-232 serial port). That COM port is onboard, connected directly to the motherboard's logic. The motherboard has 4 SATA ports, of which only 2 are used (a HD and a optical drive).

Recently, the computer started to have random boot failures like this:

```
Auto-detecting SATA1...IDE Hard Disk
Auto-detecting SATA2...ATAPI CD-ROM
(...)
3rd Master Hard Disk Error
```

This is the second computer that starts to have this. With the first one, the frequency of the failures increased until the computer could no longer boot. That was not long ago and the only common things between the 2 machines are the use of the COM port with the same chromatograph and the software. The HD and motherboard are not the same (not even same manufacturer). I think it's safe to assume the software and OS are not the cause of the problem, and it doesn't seem like a coincidence.

Could something like an over voltage or current leak in the COM port damage the SATA-related logic on the motherboard?

Comment: Can it happen: I suppose it's possible both motherboards have the exact same flaw, but that is very unlikely, given they were different manufactures and there is literally no reason to connect the COM ports to the SATA ports.  In other words if you took a voltage measurement between each pin on both ports they would be open.  This means the only possible way to cause damage would the voltage would have to arc (which goes back to the design flaw) thats unlikely.

Comment: It is more likely your hard drive has/or "is about to"  die.  Either that or the controller died of old age.

Comment: @cybernard, the hard-drive is in SATA1, the error is in SATA3. With the other computer the HD is fine. By "controller" you mean the SATA controller of the motherboard?

Comment: yes, I mean the sata controller on the motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound, both SATA and COM are serial 2-way communication ports, so when the second computer started to show the same behaviour as the first I thought there could be some relation and guessed some electrical interference. This error on the 2nd computer happened a few days ago and disappeared on a reboot, and today the error only went away after disconnecting and reconnecting the RAM sticks.

Comment: Like I said COM and SATA are not connected to one another.  Don't incorrectly connect two separate independent events and protocols and conclude there is a causation.

Comment: OK, so most likely this is just a coincidence of two motherboards failing of age since both were/are old, right? COM ports are not usual anymore, so for a newer motherboard to be able to talk with that chromatograph we would have to try our luck with a COM-to-USB converter which is not a simple COM connector wired to a USB connector, right?